# How to prevent AMQP (RabbitMQ) message from being black holed when the connection to the broker dies?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

For example, if there's a network outage and your producer loses connection to your RabbitMQ broke, how can you prevent messages from being black holed that need to be queued up? I have a few ideas one of them being to write all your messages to a local db and remove them once they're acked and periodically resend after some time period, but that only works if your connection factory is set to have the publisher confirm.

Comment: What is the source of your messages?

Comment: I'm just generating messages from my test application to simulate event logging. I'm essentially trying to create a durable producer. Is there a way to detect when you can reconnect to RabbitMQ also? I see there's a ConnectionListener interface, but it seems you cannot send messages to flush an internal queue in the ConnectionListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm just generating messages from my test application to simulate event logging. I'm essentially trying to create a durable producer. Is there a way to detect when you can reconnect to RabbitMQ also? I see there's a ConnectionListener interface, but it seems you cannot send messages to flush an internal queue in the ConnectionListener.

If you have a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` (perhaps listening to a dummy queue) it will keep trying to reconnect (and fire the connection listener when successful). Or you can have a simple looper that calls `createConnection()` on the connection factory from time-to-time (it won't create a new connection each time, just return the single shared connection - if open); this will also fire the listener when a new connection is made.

You can use transactions instead of publisher confirms - but they're much slower due to the handshake. It depends on what your performance requirements are.

Comment: Thanks! The looper on createConnection() worked like a charm for me.